# How to open a webview inside a frame in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

What I need is to load HTML code inside a frame in a page in an Ionic app, without opening a new window or covering the rest of the page.

The idea is to have a frame that opens a web page without covering or disrupting the rest of the page like the header, buttons, etc.

Basically, what I want to do is the equivalent to an Android WebView in an Ionic framework app.

Is this possible?

There is no much code, is a simple "message details" page for a messaging app, is just that the messages have to be displayed as a web page.

```
<ion-view view-title="Detalles de mensaje" class="discover-page">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon-round" ng-click="openPopover($event)">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios7-arrow-back" ng-click="goBack()">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content scroll="false">

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I need to show the header with the top buttons and the webview below them.

Comment: Did you try Angular UI routing? Please post some code.

Comment: I've been reading about it but no luck just yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just want to show the any web view in your app with your header. Yes it is possible with **iframe html tag**. But it is possible only for http web views not for https web views like paypal.

Comment: Good, but I can't scroll (the scrolling attribute is not supported in HTML5). And is there a way for displaying https webviews?

Comment: Which ionic version, you are using in your app? I think, you need to update the ionic and cordova versions and for https webviews, I'm also trying to find the way..

Comment: You can't open some https not all in iframe. I have tried to open the paypal in iframe with my app header and back button but paypal not allowed it.